# Render only child element in DOM instead of the whole JSX element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, video.js, react-dom

I copied this file from a user showing how to display a video using an npm library called videoJS:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import VideoJs from 'video.js'


const videoJsOptions = {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: true,
  fluid: false,
  loop: true,
  width: '100%',
  aspectRatio: '4:3',
  children: [
      'MediaLoader'
  ],
}

const VideoPlayer = ({ url }) => {
  const videoContainer = useRef()

  //  Setup the player
  useEffect(() => {

    //  Setting content like this because player.dispose() remove also the html content
    videoContainer.current.innerHTML = `
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video class="video-js" />
      </div>
    `

    //  Setting logger level to all for dev
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      VideoJs.log('all')
    }

    const player = VideoJs(videoContainer.current.querySelector('video'), videoJsOptions, async () => {
      player.src({ src: url, type: 'video/mp4' });
    })

    //  When destruct dispose the player
    return () => player.dispose()
  }, [url])

  console.log(videoContainer)
  
  return <div ref={videoContainer} />
}

export default VideoPlayer
```

the problem is that there is this parent div rendered which pushes the actual video far below the page:
[image]

I'd like to remove this parent div while only keeping the video element. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You're actively rendering the parent div when you set `videoContainer.current.innerHTML = \`<div data-vjs-player><video class="video-js" /></div>\``...why not just render the `<video />` element?

Comment: Hi, @SethLutske thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that was the first thing I tried. It seems to auto-generate this parent div:

Comment: <div id="vjs_video_85" class="video-js vjs_video_85-dimensions vjs-fluid vjs-controls-enabled vjs-touch-enabled vjs-workinghover vjs-v7 vjs-has-started vjs-user-inactive vjs-playing" tabindex="-1" role="region" lang="en" aria-label="Video Player"></div>

Comment: why not just target the parent div with css and remove all the margin and padding?

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I used !important on padding-top in the .video-js class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the *video.js* CSS files. For example:

```
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.min.css';
```

In the demo I load the CSS files from the CDN, and as you can see it looks fine.

Note: the demo uses my implementation of *video.js* in React. The internal component `Player` exposes an imperative API to the parent, and since the JSX inside is not dependent on changing props it won't re-render the actual DOM. It will only dispose of the player when it's unmounted.

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } = React;

const videoJsOptions = {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: true,
  loop: true,
  width: '100%',
  aspectRatio: '16:9',
  children: [
      'MediaLoader'
  ],
}

const Player = forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  const video = useRef();
  const player = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    player.current = videojs(video.current, videoJsOptions);
    
    return () => {
      player.current.dispose();
    };
  }, []);
  
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    play: (src, type) => {
      const p = player.current;
      
      p.ready(() => {
        p.src({ src, type });
      });
    }
  }));
  
  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video className="video-js" ref={video} />
    </div>
  );
});

const VideoPlayer = ({ url, type = 'video/mp4' }) => {
  const player = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    player.current.play(url, type);
  }, [url, type]);
  
  return <Player ref={player} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <VideoPlayer url="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" />,
  root
);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.0.0/video.min.js" integrity="sha512-LiILFcpZ9QKSH41UkK59Zag/7enHzqjr5lO2M0wGqGn8W19A/x2rV3iufAHkEtrln+Bt+Zv1U6NlLIp+lEqeWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.0.0/alt/video-js-cdn.min.css" integrity="sha512-zki7IiwYvLzVZouKA+V/vtIuW7cK8M2ug1kaRBItuBWG8TDvA6jrtjhKPOrz3RFGpt9OQC/xE7DUfsrHxoBXxg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id="root"></div>
```